# SP2013 Calendar Overlays two colors per calendar

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I'd like to have a default color in my calendar overlay and another color if my calendar attribute - (category) is a specific value. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps from Planet Wilson: http://www.planetwilson.co.uk/sharepoint-2013-colour-calendar-v2/. (I can't post a link).

It uses a js file to give you full control over the colors meaning you can use any color you would like. Summarized steps below but link contains full instructions.

1. You'll need a calculated column that uses the following formula: = "|||" & [Category] & "|||" & [Title]
2. You'll need to default the view to the calculated column for it's day, month and weekly view
3. Add a content editor to your page and include a reference to the script
4. Edit the script to change the colors by matching your columns names to those in the script

From this script I'm able to add the default color and highlight color in the JS script.

Note: There is also a 2010 version available.